# How do I prevent child affected for transform scale in css3?

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.parent {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover .parent {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(300);
            transform: scaleX(300);
}

.wrapper . parent .child {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
}
```

I want to scale only .parent element when hovering .wrapper div. But it also affects two div (parent and child) although give transform:none property for .child div. How do I prevent .child affected?

http://jsfiddle.net/cdmkoao4/1/

Comment: Not doable I'm afraid, usually it should work reversing the `transform` of the inner element, but looks like it's not the case with `scaleX`... for some weird reasons. I would go with `width`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I guess you're right, but I 'll wait for a better scalex answer.

Comment: The scaleX gives also weird results in Chrome. FF makes the transition totally smooth, while the other has strange squared surfaces. Just you wait! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `transform: scaleX` try changing the width

```
.wrapper:hover .parent {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdmkoao4/3/

**Update:**

Honestly, I don't see any reason why would you use `scaleX` instead of `width`, but this is the only solution that I came up with. Simply don't nest `.child` with `.parent`, make them separate divs with `position: absolute`. On hover, you'd `scaleX` only `.parent`, while you'd only change the `opacity` of `.child` (I still used same classes even though they don't have `parent-child` status anymore).

http://jsfiddle.net/cdmkoao4/9/

You'd need to play a bit with `transition-delay` time to get the exact effect you want.

Comment: @Davin This is a nice approach to sample, but project is too complex and this is just a piece of project. So I must use scalex for my project.But thank you for your answer.It's useful

Comment: **Position**, **scale**, **rotation** and **opacity** are super cheap in modern browsers and should aways be prefered if possible. If you use anything else, you will probably not get 60 frames per second animations.